# React Native App Returns "Application not registered" on Android

Tags: android, react-native

My React Native app (configured with the name "ctipsApp") works perfectly on iOS, but when running "react-native run-android", or starting it with Android Studio, the app returns the following error:

> Application ctipsApp has not been registered. This is either due to a
>   require() error during initialization or failure to call
>   AppRegistry.registerComponent

I had setup the project via the command "react-native init ctipsApp" and the Android files show that this is the configured name. The index.android.js file also clearly contains the `AppRegistry.registerComponent` function and I am certain the file is being executed.

When I press the `Reload` button inside the app, it then returns the error that it couldn't connect to the development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the app to computer interface is failing to load the needed files. This can be temporarily solved by running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, which will fix the issue in connecting. (If the command adb can't be found run the full path such as `/Users/noah/Library/Android/sdk//platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`)
However, if you try to build the app and distribute it, then this solution won't fix the problem. To do that, you'll need to cache the bundle file that `localhost:8081` provides.

1. Navigate to your project's root directory.
2. Run `react-native start` if the development server isn't already running.
3. Execute `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`.

You now have cached the bundle file in the Android assets folder. Whenever you update the code you will need to replace the cache with an updated version via the same steps as detailed above.